# Mysql Query Optimization for Speed

Tags: mysql

Newb on Advanced SQL queries so thank you in advance!

I have 2 tables, monitors and stats. The stats table is 1 million plus rows. I look up the monitors I want and then query the stats table for the latest entry. Due to the size of the stats table - it is slow, 15+ seconds.

```
select `Service`.`monitors`.`host` AS `host`,
       `Service`.`monitors`.`port` AS `port`,
       `Service`.`monitors`.`alias` AS `alias`,
       (select `Service`.`stats`.`value` 
        from `Service`.`stats` 
        where (
            concat('monitor',
                 cast(`Service`.`monitors`.`id` as char charset utf8)) 
            = convert(`Service`.`stats`.`series` using utf8)) 
        order by `Service`.`stats`.`key` desc limit 1) AS `val` 
from   `Service`.`monitors` 
where  (`Service`.`monitors`.`host` like '%te1%')
```

stats.key values are unix timestamps but the column is INT and I can't convert it for various reasons. Would MAX INT work faster that the limit 1?

Any suggestions on query structure much appreciated!

Comment: What's the output of `EXPLAIN...`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is data your data is not well organized in the first hand; if you need to do operations on every where and to insert a subquery, the MySQL optimizer will *never* find a way to optimize your query and scan less rows for the result.

Comment: Agreed - I'm trying to improve performance as much as possible before redoing a database design.